Can I avoid races with nvmlDeviceSetApplicationsClocks for context creation?
Consider the NVIDIA NVML function:
nvmlReturn_t nvmlDeviceSetApplicationsClocks ( 
    nvmlDevice_t  device,
    unsigned int  memClockMHz,
    unsigned int  graphicsClockMHz 
);

The NVML documentation says that

... [the] CUDA driver requests these clocks during context creation, which means this property defines clocks at which CUDA applications will be running...

so, if I want to create a device context with fixed clocks, I call this, create context, then call nvmlDeviceResetApplicationsClocks(). Right? Well, not so fast. What if I have several threads running in parallel? Each of them, after all, can create CUDA contexts. So how do I prevent the race conditions such as:

Thread 1 sets app clocks
Thread 2 sets app clocks
Thread 1 creates context
Thread 1 resets app clocks
Thread 2 creates context
Thread 2 resets app clocks

in this situation, neither threads gets the clocks they wanted on the context. And while this might be a bit contrived, here's a much simpler example:

Thread 1 sets app clocks
Thread 1 creates context
Thread 2 creates context, naively
Thread 1 resets app clocks

One might say "Oh, just protect the context creation calls with a mutex" - and that's fine if you control the code running on all threads, but - typically, you don't; it's some library which creates threads to run its stuff.
So, is there a way to "weld" the context creation and the clock setting together in a race-free manner?
